# Codeginiter: Get the a URI segment of a page and add it to the URL of its redirect page

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, uri

So I have these 2 pages
IF the URL of **page1** is:   ***http://localhost/project/page1/page1/5***

And there's a link in that page that redirects to **page2** with the URL:

***http://localhost/project/page2/page2/2***
(its 3rd segment - **2** is from dropdown value selected)

Is it possible to make the redirected page - **page2** with a URL like this:
***http://localhost/project/page2/page2/5/2***

-so that I could do something with page1's value, like querying dynamically in the database.

**VIEW in page1:**

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
  <select id="p2_val">

      <?php 
          foreach($v_p2 as $row) {
      ?> 
      <option 
          value="<?php  echo base_url('page2/page2/').$row->p2_val;?>">
          <?php echo $row->p2_num; ?>
      </option>
      <?php }  ?> 

  </select>

      <input  class="SubmitButton" type="submit" 
      name="SUBMITBUTTON" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

**Controller in page1:**

```
class Page1 extends CI_Controller{

     public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct(); 
            $this->load->model('page1_model');

        }

    public function page1(){
        if($this->session->userdata('logged')){

            $this->load->model('page1_model');

            $data["v_p2"] = $this->page1_model->v_p2($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

            $this->load->view('pages/page1', $data);

            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }

    }
```

**Controller of page2:**

class Page2 extends CI_Controller{

```
     public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct(); 
            $this->load->model('page2_model');

        }

    public function page2(){
        if($this->session->userdata('logged')){

            $this->load->model('page2_model');

            $data["get_p2"] = $this->page2_model->get_p2($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

            $this->load->view('pages/page2', $data);

            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }

    }
```

Comment: 1. as much as i know this is not possible still you can check https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

2. Why do u wanna pass your value in url its really not secured

Comment: Define what your controllers and methods are. Is page 2 and 1 controllers in the subdir projects? Is the second page definition a method of those controllers? This is very confusing without knowing more.

Comment: @sayalok I can't seem to get around with routing in this. Is it still not secure if these pages session is logged?

Comment: @kurwaaa no and how much data u can send via url whicle u need to send big amount of data what will u do ?

Comment: @Alex how about the edit, is that it? and yeah both are on the same dir.

Comment: Why do you want to have page2 twice in the url? Just make the method in the controller index and it won't repeat.

Comment: @Alex It's page1's uri segment I have to use twice and because I have to do something with the two values to get the desired output, using: $this->uri->segment(n).

Comment: @Alex specifically, I need $this->uri->segment(3) and $this->uri->segment(4) for condtional statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I changed view of page1 into:***

```
  <option 
      value="<?php  echo base_url('page2/page2/').$row->p1_val.'/'.$row->p2_val;?>">
      <?php echo $row->p2_num; ?>
  </option>
```

***No change in the controllers, just worked around with models by using:***

```
$this->uri->segment();
```

***- Most changes were then in the db queries I made.***
- Since I added additional segment in page2, I added **" ../ "** to the paths of the assets.

***sample - model for page2:***

```
   function v_p2($data){
        $p1_val = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $p2_val = $this->uri->segment(4); 

         //DO smth with $p1_val & $p2_val
         //These values were used for querying


}
```

Comment: Just make sure that if you aren't using query builder that you are manually escaping the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I'm understanding you but you can do:

```
public function page2($var1, $var2){

}
```

http://localhost/project/page2/page2/5/2

where `$var1` is `5`, and `$var2` is `2` in the above url

Comment: thank  you for taking the time to answer. I just recently solved it.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can answer your own question so that it may help people in the future w a similar issue.

Comment: yea, I jus answered thanks. not sure if this is clear enough